# How to draw things without turtle in python

Tags: python

I was trying to draw a square using asterisks but this code was not working 
This is the code

```
def drawStar(numStars):
    for x in range(0,numStars):
        print("* ")

def menu():
    # prompting the user to pick what they want drawn
    input("Welcome to my draw shapes program ")
    print("What would you like me to draw")
    input(" Draw a Square (1)\n Draw a Rectangle (2)\n Draw a Rectangle (2)\n Draw an Arrow Head (3)\n Exit (4)")

def drawSquare():
   width = int(input("What is the width of your square "))
   for x in range(0,width):
        drawStar(width)
drawSquare()
```

This is the output i kept getting

```
What is the width of your square 2
* 
* 
None
* 
* 
None
```

Comment: `drawStar` `return`s `None`; `drawSquare` `return`s `None` and doesn't `print` anything

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> print("* ")
> ```

The [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function by default prints a newline character after the data you provide.  That is why you see each asterisk (and space) on a separate line.  The `print()` function accepts a keyword argument named `end` to specify something else to print at the end.

You probably want something like this:

```
def drawStar(numStars):
    for x in range(0,numStars):
        print("* ", end='')
    print()
```

or alternatively, you can use the feature of python that strings can be multiplied by a number:

```
def drawStar(numStars):
    print( "* " * numStars )
```

Answer (score -1):

Rectangle:

```
m, n = 10, 10
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print('*' if i in [0, n-1] or j in [0, m-1] else ' ', end='')
    print()
```

Triangle:

```
m, n = 10, 10
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print('*' if i in [j, m-1] or j == 0 else ' ', end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Please add some narrative. While a code dump will help OP with the immediate problem of submitting an assignment, a bit of narrative will help future improvement a lot more.